# Pass an array in express to an ejs file

Tags: arrays, express

I'm trying to print the contents of a form saved in an array called 'userInfo' to an ejs file but I keep an error saying "userInfo is not defined" what am I doing wrong?

Here is the JS code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express(),
    port = 3000,
    userInfo = [];


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/formResults', function(req, res) {
    userInfo.name = req.body.name;
    userInfo.local = req.body.dojoLocation;
    userInfo.lang = req.body.language;
    userInfo.comment = req.body.comment;

    console.log(userInfo);

    res.redirect('/results')
});

app.get('/results', function(req, res) {
    res.render('results', {users: userInfo});

})

app.listen(port, function(req, res) {
    console.log('server running on port: ' + port)
});
```

Here is what's on the ejs file

Form Results

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<userInfo.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%= userInfo[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help or advice offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you're passing to EJS is called `users`, not `userInfo`:

```
res.render('results', { users: userInfo });
                        ^^^^^
```

So your template should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%= users[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

However, even though you declare `userInfo` to be an array, you're using it as an object. Try this instead:

```
app.post('/formResults', function(req, res) {
  userInfo.push({
    name    : req.body.name,
    local   : req.body.dojoLocation,
    lang    : req.body.language,
    comment : req.body.comment
  });

  console.log(userInfo);

  res.redirect('/results')
});
```

(`userInfo.push()` adds a new object to the array called `userInfo` each time a request to `/formResults` is made, which I assume is what you want)

And your template should reference the object properties (`name`, for instance):

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%= users[i].name %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help robertklep. 

Could you just explain this bit one more time?
app.post('/formResults', function(req, res) {
  userInfo.push({
    name    : req.body.name,
    local   : req.body.dojoLocation,
    lang    : req.body.language,
    comment : req.body.comment
  });

  console.log(userInfo);

  res.redirect('/results')
});

Comment: @BenJohnson I added a bit more clarification, I hope it's enough. If not, can you be more specific about what you want explained?